# NDBaI Index calculation in GEE- JS

Tags: threshold, google-earth-engine, landsat

I am having difficulty in generating the NDBaI index using Landsat 8 correctly, the range of values is not ranging from -1 to 1. Either the values are all negative or it has a very small range from 0.8 to 0.9 which is unrealistic wrt the on ground features. My study area is a forest with a buffer around it.

The formula-

[image: The formula used]

The range shows as -1 to 1 but when I click inspector and check on two different land features(forest and builtup) the values are all only in negative.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some information on your input datasets? Maybe their scales are not matching?

Comment: @malin-fischer Input Dataset is Landsat 8 (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2). I am doing the analysis in Google Earth Engine, and the scales of both the bands have been resampled to the same resolution (30m) and the bands have also been multiplied with the scale factor as mentioned in the metadata.